# Prevent concurrent access and inserts with MySQL and InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I'm currently making an instant winning game with the following rule : the first user to register at least half an hour after the last one did wins. So users can win every half an hour. If no one registers during a few hours, the first one to register wins.

Server uses PHP 5.2.0, which explains I don't use the DateTime class. My table winnertable is InnoDB.

This part of my script is called by each client upon user registration and decides wether the user has won or not :

```
$currentTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// We're looking for the last winner in the winners table
$res = $dbh->query("SELECT date FROM winnertable ORDER BY id DESC")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(empty($res)){
    // If there is no last winner then the user wins
    $winner = true;
}else{
    // If there is already a last winner, we check the date of win, if superior to half an hour, the user wins 
    if(strtotime($currentTime)-strtotime($res["date"])>=1800){
        // Last winner was half an hour ago : winner
        $winner = true;
    }
}

// if the winner flag is set to true, add the user id to the winners table along with the date of winning
if($winner){
    $dbh->query("INSERT INTO winnertable (id_main, date) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '".$currentTime."')");
}
```

The next page has to show the result to the user so he knows if he has won or not. So I can't make a CRON job to decide afterwards.

This script is flawed because if accessed by multiple clients at the exact same time, it can probably make multiple clients win.

I've read some solutions around :

- Using locks : but I don't know the performance cost. Also, I've read that MyIsam tables locked the whole table while InnoDB ones locked only selected rows that were marked for update. And I don't know what to do from there.
- Making my "date" column UNIQUE should prevent multiple insertions of the same date and seems to be an elegant workaround but it seems a bit too easy to be trusted and I would really like your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally decided to think the problem differently and decided to post the solution as it might help some people.

I've read on InnoDB tables row level lock and did the following :

Stmt #1 : UPDATE winnertable SET id_main=[id] WHERE date_add(next_date, INTERVAL X SECOND) < NOW() AND id_main = 0

If PDO returns a modified row ($stmt->rowCount()) then it's the winner and you have to insert a new line in winnertable for the next winner :

Stmt #2 (conditional) : INSERT INTO winnertable SET next_date=NOW()

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a further stage to the situation, whereby you have another temporary table that stores 'potential' winners - the ones that satisfy the winning criteria. Then run a SELECT on that as a secondary action ordering by date, index in ascending order with a limit of one. Take that value and add it to the real winners table and use that as the basis for the next winning calculation, and clear out the temporary table. That way you should only ever get one winner. It would add overhead of course, but it's only going to be every half an hour that it happens so I don't think it should be too much of an issue.

Comment: I don't see how this is not just displacing the problem from the main table to the secondary one. If there are many registrations within a second, each of them being a potential winner, one client might clear the potential winners table while others might still be writing in it, and therefore each client will have its own version of who has won.

Comment: If you were capturing ALL the entries in one table, it would be fairly trivial to work out the winners post-event. However I presume you only want the winners on one table. So my thinking for the second table was an attempt to capture all the entries leading up to the next winner. The choice of winner event could then happen on a separate timed event, such as a chron object, therefore removing the confusion by multiple scripts called by the applicants trying to decide a winner. The Chron object would clear the 'buffer' table and add the winner to the winners list and then notify the winner.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to find the winner during the execution of the script to show it to the user. But your idea could still be good : 1) I could insert everyone in the table, 2) find the last winner, assuming there is a "win" column, calculate if the date of the last win > 1/2h 3) If true, select all entries where date > last win + 1/2h, order by ID ASC, and mark the first one win=1. Request could be concurrent but would produce the same result no ?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that you mentioned you can't use a cron job. That kind of blows my idea then! Sorry.

Comment: It's hurting my head thinking about it! ... you could retain a buffer with maybe an hours worth of entries, and like you say the result should be the same, but that would require a further check against the winners table I think. In theory it should only resolve to a single winner.

Comment: It feels this : http://pastebin.com/HL6qFZsK could be the solution. Request on line 8, even if concurrent, will automatically retrieve the good ID, no ? It's somewhat an adaptation of your solution.

Comment: Yes, if you have a separate select after writing to the table then the result can be sorted on the DATE and ID, and therefore only one result can be returned. If you wanted only winners in the final table though you'd could use the buffer idea in the same way, and do the 1/2 hr date comparison with the latest entry in the winners table, making sure to copy the winner into the winners table before flushing the buffer table.